# Series of inverse functions, unclear numerical constant

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, inverse

I was answering another question here and came up with this simple illustrative example that should have an analytic solution. Indeed it has, but I do not understand it. In particular, where 85 is coming from?

```
g[x_]:=BesselJ[0,x]
f[x_]:=Exp[x]
Series[f[InverseFunction[g][y]],{y,0,0}]
Out[1]= E^-BesselJZero[0,85]+O[y]^1
```

Comment: I get `E^-BesselJZero[0, 1] + SeriesData[y, 0, {}, 0, 1, 1]`, maybe try with a fresh kernel ?

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what That's a fresh kernel :) My `$Version` is `11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 27, 2017)`

Comment: Mine is 12.1.1; I confirm that I get the same as you with 11.1.1.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what Bug?

Comment: I'd wait for others to confirm but you could already report it to Wolfram.

Comment: MMA 12.1.0 E^-BesselJZero[0,1]+O[y]^1